# Which computer processor gives better performance for android studio? AMD or Intel?

Tags: android, android-studio, processor

I am thinking of upgrading my processor. As many people say that AMD's multicore processor gives better performances in video editing software. But others say that for emulator and other purposes android studio or IntelliJ performs better in Intel processors. It would be a great help to know more details about the android studio's performance in both processors.

Comment: Emulator uses HAXM, only available on Intel

Comment: Yes i heard that. But some of my contacts are running emulator in amd processors too. That's why i was asking is there anything new in amd ryzen?

Comment: Official source confirm your point https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Answer (score 1):

For Android development I suggest go with minimum intell i5 7th gen or more and for high budget intell i7 5th gen or more.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Using SSD will give you more performance then selecting processor. When i was using HDD then i was unable to run android studio and emulator smoothly together. After installing SSD now I am using 3-4 android studio window with emulator and chrome browser.
SSD would be must for development purpose.

Comment: Yes i have upgraded my storage from HDD to SSD. I also play games so i have decided to change CPU too. That's why asking. Thanks for your help.